# How to allow users to cancel their paypal subscription on the site, instead of going thru paypal CP?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I have read thru their API (https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECRecurringPayments), but I dont fully understand how to use it.

Are there any PHP examples on how to utilize this? I use IPN + express checkout to create subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus API call to cancel/suspend or re-activate a recurring payments profile.
Have a look at the doc on https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus

I don't have any sample code at hand, but it shouldn't be too hard to adapt a different example to this. E.g. the NVP SDK sample code at https://www.x.com/